# How to pass a single quote ( ' ) from user input to a stored procedure, avoiding SQL injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web

Our application takes a user's name as input from the frontend, and sometimes the name has a single quote. So how do I pass the name entered to a stored procedure if the name contains a single quote (`'`)?

We can not pass a single quote (`'`) directly to stored procedure input, as it may cause SQL injection.

Database Used: SQL Server 2008 
Application: ASP.NET C# 4.0

Comment: encryp it as #bubu then decrypt at sql server sp as '

Comment: can you provide your code?

Answer (score 3):

Use parameterized queries. For instance,

```
var command = new SqlCommand("select * from person where firstname = @firstname");
SqlParameter parameter  = new SqlParameter();
parameter.ParameterName = "@firstname";
parameter.Value= "D'Jork";
command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use  parameterized query.Single quotes are handled by them.

You can read in depth about it at: [Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

You need to double it up:

```
INSERT INTO myTable(text) VALUES ('I don''t like this!')
```

But as the previous poster has stated... using parameters is better because it is safer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `SqlCommandBuilder.QuoteIdentifier(/* params */)`:

```
var sqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder();
var sqlCommand = string.Format("EXEC dbo.SomeProcedure '{0}'",
                         sqlCommandBuilder.QuoteIdentifier("Jack's name"));

// futher sql command process
```

More on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.quoteidentifier%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Although replacing single quote with double quote before calling stored procedure should also work, something like this will also work:

@parameter = 'Test'' A''B''C' -- Test' A'B'C

But if you don't want to go this way, you can also try with

```
Use SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
```

just before hitting the query that will also work, but remember we need QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON for many situations.